# Perl CPAN: module for network-connectivity

Tags: perl, http, cpan

I need to check the network-availability of some webservers (HTTP/HTTPS).
For that I just need ip/dns and port. But I have a list of URLs.
And I would like to use a CPAN-module for that job.

But:
- HTTP::Tiny, LWP::UserAgent, ... checks the HTTP-stats, not the network-status. I need to check the 2nd (connection established) and I dont care about the HTTP-header and content.

- A simple socket does not support URL-format for defining the destination.
  It needs ip and port.

So any ideas if a HTTP-module also provides a network-status??

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just test error codes? If it's "can't connect" or "hostname not found", interpret accordingly.

Comment: I like the direct way. Instead of parsing error-codes I would rather parse URLs and go with the socket.

Comment: Because it does not support a whole URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse URLs to obtain the host and port using [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module.

Creating a connection can be done using the functions provided by [Socket](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Socket), or using the higher-level class [IO::Socket::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket::IP).